# how to use namespace in gem Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I have 2 controller, 1 for user and 1 for admin.

controllers/articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def show 
    @article = Article.find(parmas[:id])
    authorize @article
  end
  ...
end
```

controllers/admin/articles_controller.rb

```
class Admin::ArticlesController < AdminController
  ...
  def show 
    @article = Article.find(parmas[:id])
    authorize @article
  end
  ...
end
```

And i have 2 file policy
policies/article_policy.rb

```
class ArticlePolicy
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
  autoload :Admin

  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def show?
    # allow show for every user. 
    true 
  end  
end
```

And one file policies/admin/article_policy.rb

```
class Admin::ArticlePolicy

  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def show?
    # only show if use have role manager 
    user.manager? 
  end  
end
```

but when i use a account user to show articles at /admin/articles/1/. It show normaly, Should is "Access denied".

How to fix this? (I use gem pundit 1.10).

Answer (score 13):

Use the authorize method to pass the namespace as a parameter.

```
class ArticlesController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def show 
    @article = Article.find(parmas[:id])
    authorize [:admin, @article]
  end
  ...
end
```